# App crashes when launch can't get what happen and i also add all activity in manifest.xml

Tags: android, fatal-error, runtimeexception, android-runtime

this is my layout file

```
                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/rto"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="RTO Number" >

                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/from"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="From" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/to"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10" 
                            android:hint="To"/>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/start_tracking"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="START TRACKING" />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

ManiActivity.java

```
                            package com.example.gsrtc_driver;

                        import android.location.Location;
                        import android.location.LocationListener;
                        import android.location.LocationManager;
                        import android.os.Bundle;
                        import android.app.Activity;
                        import android.content.Context;
                        import android.content.Intent;
                        import android.view.Menu;
                        import android.view.View;
                        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
                        import android.widget.Button;
                        import android.widget.EditText;

                        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

                            static String Bus_latitude = "BUS_LAT";
                            static String Bus_longitude = "BUS_LON";
                            static String TAG_RTO = "BUS_RTO";
                            static String TAG_FROM = "BUS_FROM";
                            static String  TAG_TO = "BUS_TO";

                            EditText RTO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rto);
                            EditText FROM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
                            EditText TO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
                            Button Start_Tracking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_tracking);

                            String RTO_NO = RTO.getText().toString();
                            String FROM_STRING = FROM.getText().toString();
                            String TO_STRING = TO.getText().toString();


                            // GET LOCATION OF DRIVER


                            LocationManager lm;
                            LocationListener locationListener;


                            @Override
                            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                                Start_Tracking.setOnClickListener(this);


                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                 lm = (LocationManager)
                                         getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                                         locationListener = new MyLocationListener();


                                        // ---request location updates---
                                            locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                                            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                                1000,1000, locationListener);


                            }

                            public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    double latitude = arg0.getLatitude();
                                    double longitude =  arg0.getLongitude();

                                     String Bus_lat = Double.toString(latitude);
                                     String Bus_lon = Double.toString(longitude);

                                     Intent starttracking = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Start_Tracking.class);

                                     starttracking.putExtra(Bus_lat, Bus_latitude);
                                     starttracking.putExtra(Bus_lon, Bus_longitude);
                                     starttracking.putExtra(RTO_NO, TAG_RTO);
                                     starttracking.putExtra(FROM_STRING,TAG_FROM );
                                     starttracking.putExtra(TO_STRING,TAG_TO );

                                     startActivity(starttracking);

                                     lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                                }



                                @Override
                                public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                            }
                        }
```

07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at com.example.gsrtc_driver.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:24)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
07-20 05:48:24.134: E/AndroidRuntime(1538):     ... 11 more

androidmanifest.xml

this is my manifest.xml

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="com.example.gsrtc_driver"
                android:versionCode="1"
                android:versionName="1.0" >

                <uses-sdk
                    android:minSdkVersion="8"
                    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
             <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                    <activity
                        android:name="in.online.gsrtc.DRIVER.MainActivity"
                        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                    <activity
                        android:name="in.online.gsrtc.DRIVER.Start_Tracking"
                        android:label="@string/title_activity_start__tracking" >
                    </activity>
                </application>

            </manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Please post some more explanation and relevant parts of your code.

Comment: yes i added in manifest.xml

Comment: can you post your manifest.xml and the full stacktrace?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke here it is  in MainActivity.java   i add on click listener on button and put extra values in it [Intent starttracking = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Start_Tracking.class);
    
    starttracking.putExtra(Bus_lat, Bus_latitude);
    starttracking.putExtra(Bus_lon, Bus_longitude);
    starttracking.putExtra(RTO_NO, TAG_RTO);
    starttracking.putExtra(FROM_STRING,TAG_FROM );
    starttracking.putExtra(TO_STRING,TAG_TO );
    
    startActivity(starttracking);
    ]

Comment: by the info you provide i just can tell you that findviewbyid returns null, probably because you are looking for a view that does not belong to the current activity's view hierarchy.

Comment: @Xabier ther is only one activity that has component and second one is blank xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see.. you are trying to assign the widgets when the view is not created yet, try the following code:

Change:

```
EditText RTO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rto);
EditText FROM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
EditText TO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
Button Start_Tracking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_tracking);

String RTO_NO = RTO.getText().toString();
String FROM_STRING = FROM.getText().toString();
String TO_STRING = TO.getText().toString();
```

to:

```
EditText RTO;
EditText FROM;
EditText TO;
Button Start_Tracking;

String RTO_NO;
String FROM_STRING;
String TO_STRING;
```

then, in the onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RTO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rto);
    FROM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.from);
    TO = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to);
    Start_Tracking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_tracking);

    RTO_NO = RTO.getText().toString();
    FROM_STRING = FROM.getText().toString();
    TO_STRING = TO.getText().toString();


    Start_Tracking.setOnClickListener(this);


}
```

Comment: you spot error perfectly i will try this solution to solve my error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is a problem in findViewById in your Activity.

Can you please post your Activity code and activity layout code?

**Edit:**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText mSampleEdit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSampleEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sampleEdit);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your manifest can you try writing packageNames lowercased? I see also other strange things in term of Java convention. I would rename Start_Tracking to StartTracking for example.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java This is a good starting point for improving your code as well.

Comment: ya but it means i have to make whole project from start and this kinda errors comes often with lower case package name also... can you provide exact solution ? i am stuck in this from last 10 days

Comment: Move your findViewById in the onCreate method. You cannot define them like you did. Define your widget and in the onCreate method assign them the corresponding view using the id

Comment: i don't know about findviewbyid method that it can't be define outside  and also when i want to use value of edittext in MyLocationListener class it show error so i did it globally.

Comment: But it's wrong logically. In the onCreate the activity knows with layout to use. If you do like you did the activity doesn't know where to get your editexts from. I would suggest you to change your code as I did in my edited answer. Keep the edittext as an instance variable but initialize it in onCreate